# 変数　asrについて

Tags: python, pepper, choregraphe

ChoregrapheのSpeech Reco.ボックスのソースを解析してます。

ソースを見ると

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self, False)
        try:
            self.asr = ALProxy("ALSpeechRecognition")
```

とありますが、self.asrのasrという変数はどの様な意味合いの変数なのでしょうか？

selfはChoregrapheのSpeech Reco.ボックス自身を指し示していると認識していますが、asrという変数に値を代入することにより、よりOS側に何か命令を送ってるのでしょうか？
(Googleで検索したらASR moduleと言うキーワードを見つけましたが、より細かい説明は見つけられませんでした。)

以上よろしくお願いします。

Comment: **A**L**S**peech**R**econgnitionの頭文字、というだけのような...。selfはMyClassのインスタンスで, `self.asr=`はasrを定義しているだけです。OSとは全く関係ありません。ALProxyクラスは引数の文字列によってサービスが選択できるようになっているのではないかと思います。ALProxyのソースを読んでみてください。

Answer (score 1):

ご質問の書き方だと、変数の名前の意味にこだわっているように見えます。
名前自身はKenji Noguchiさんの言うように、使用するモジュールの頭文字でしょう。

答えとしては、「使用したいモジュールへのALProxy(のオブジェクト)」
であって、TCP/IPのsocketやOSのCOMポートデバイスをCreate/Openして、
そのハンドルを格納する変数と同様のものと言えます。

この場合はプログラムの個々のステップや変数の意味合いを検索するよりも、
全体の基本から調べた方が良いでしょう。
以下のサイトを参考にしてください。

Pepper NAO Choregraphe Naoqi wiki
http://naoqi.memo.wiki/d/Python%20SDK

> Key Conceptsを理解しよう
>   　Key Conceptsを一読の上以下を読み進めてください。
>
> 基本的なアプローチは
>   　•ALProxyをImportする(引用元から修正)
>   　•使用したいモジュールへのALProxyを作成する(引用元から修正)
>   　•Methodを呼び出す
>
> 上記をプログラムにすると以下のようになる。
>
> ```py
> 　from naoqi import ALProxy
> 　tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "<IP of your robot>", 9559)
> 　tts.say("Hello, world!")
> ```

NAO のプログラミング環境の基本（１） クロス・ランゲージ、クロス・プラットフォームな開発環境
http://tkawata.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/12/28/165950

> ここで AL::ALProxy がプロキシ です。
>   　プロキシ のインスタンスは特定のモジュールと通信をし、
>   　モジュール内の機能を操作、また状態を確認したり、
>   　イベントを受け取ったりすることができます。
>
> モジュールは機能ごとに細分化されています。
>   　一つの プロキシ のインスタンスは一つのモジュールと通信をすることができます。

Pepperアプリ開発 ALProxyについて
https://utage.headwaters.co.jp/blog/?p=4430

NAOqi / コレグラフ APIモジュール一覧（ver. 2.0.5）
https://qiita.com/robotstart/items/7814bb56d0b56b1ad5ae

Comment: kenji noguchiさん、kunifさんお返事ありがとうございます。分かって来ました。今後ともよろしくお願いします。