# ChoregrapheにおけるPythonについて

Tags: python, pepper, choregraphe

PepperをプログラミングができるChoregrapheは各ボックスがPythonで記述されていますが、
各ボックスはクラスの定義がされているだけで、インスタンスの生成がされていないように思われます。
[Hello World 2 - using Python in Choregraphe](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/getting_started/helloworld_choregraphe_script.html)ではコンストラクタ内で

```
self.tts= ALProxy('ALTextToSpeech')
```

とするだけで、インスタンスを生成できるとしていますが、ttsは変数でありインスタンスそのものではないように思います。
どのようにしてインスタンスを生成しているのでしょうか。

Comment: こちらの質問の変種(少し違う方向からの疑問)では無いですか？ [変数　asrについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40116/26370)

Comment: 確かに変種ではあると思いますが、Choregrapheのボックス内はクラスが書いてあるだけでほかのボックスなどでも特にインスタンス化していないようなので、そこが疑問に思っています。

Comment: 実際に動作する部分はシミュレータなりPepperなりの中で既に動作しているのでは？ 紹介記事回答に書いた通り、Proxy作成は通信ポート(SerialPortやTCP/IP)のOpenみたいなものですから。

Comment: なるほど、そうなのかもしれません。ありがとうございます。